# Azure Mobile Services vs Azure Notification Hubs - Which to use for Push Notifications?

Tags: azure, windows-phone-8, push-notification, azure-mobile-services, azure-notificationhub

this question could have been asked frequently but i really want to know the difference .I am totally confused .

I am planning to buy and use/implement Windows Azure  for Push Notifications ,Toast Notifications and Live Tiles for my game . I want to know which one is better ? Azure Mobile Services or Notification Hub .

These two services sound the same , in the sense that they provide all the services related to push notifications . Though Azure Mobile services has some extra features like Data storage , user authentication etc ..

I also want to know whether i can use Notification Hub service via Azure Mobile services.
Like if i had bought/paid for Windows Azure Mobile Services can i use/access Notifications Hub too.

The reason i want to use Windows Azure for my game :

1. I want to send a toast notification to the user/device when another
   user/device sends a              challenge or Request (like for eg:
   an option called "Challenge a friend").
2. Push Notifications to the Live Tile regarding "leaderboards" and
   personal highscore .The Game Mode last played etc .
3. Make these facilities available to All platforms .(Initally i am implementing on WP8 with Live tiles).

I am also aware of the Free Trial available but i am worried about the risk of being charged.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between azure notification hub and azure mobile services](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424695/difference-between-azure-notification-hub-and-azure-mobile-services)

Comment: There is a free pricing tier for Notification Hubs, so you can get that without risking being charged. However, it has limits.

Also, this question is largely a duplicate of the above link.

Answer (score 0):

Check the features/pricing of both on the official pages:

- [Azure Mobile Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/mobile-services/)

  > Azure Mobile Services provides a scalable cloud backend for building
  >   Windows Store, Windows Phone, Apple iOS, Android, and HTML/JavaScript
  >   applications. Store data in the cloud, authenticate users, and send
  >   push notifications to your application within minutes.
- [Azure Notification Hubs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/notification-hubs/)

  > Azure Notification Hubs provides a highly scalable, cross-platform
  >   push notification infrastructure that enables you to either broadcast
  >   push notifications to millions of users at once or tailor
  >   notifications to individual users. You can use Notification Hubs with
  >   any connected mobile application—whether it’s built on Azure Virtual
  >   Machines, Cloud Services, Web Sites, or Mobile Services.

Use **Azure Mobile Services** if you need a server backend for your app, where you store data and implement server side logic. **Azure Notification Hubs is included**, which you can use for push notifications.

Use only **Azure Notification Hubs** if you don't need server side data or logic or are already using another service for this and only need a service to send push notifications.

They have both FREE tiers which could fit your needs in the beginning.

Also, there is already a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19424695/594074)...