# Which Suit for Custom Push on Azure?

Tags: azure, xamarin, push-notification, cloud, azure-mobile-services

i need advice, lets say that i have an app that have **custom saved position** (latitude & longitude).

Then i need the backend (azure) **to push info** (example weather warning) to my app based on this saved position (latitude & longitude).

so, simply like this:

- Input : position (lat & long)
- Output : info (ex: warning weather) by push to device periodicaly

Which option that suit my scenario, a mobile service or notification hub on MS Azure ? already search reference about it, and still confuse.

Explanation and reference will be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Both would work so it depends on which service suits your application better. [Difference between azure notification hub and azure mobile services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424695/difference-between-azure-notification-hub-and-azure-mobile-services) provides some good details, and Azure Mobile Services uses Notification Hubs under the hood for push.